# Select records when month and day are less than current date

Tags: sql, ssms

I am using SQL Server Mgmt Studio. I need to create a formula that will only select records when the month and day of a date/time field, LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY, is less than or equal to the current month and day. For example, If LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY = 8/20/2015 and current date = 7/6/2017, exclude. If LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY = 12/21/2014 and current date = 1/15/2017, include. Date formatting is my weakness. Here is what I have tried:

```
select LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY
    from LAW_TAEEMASTER
    WHERE day(LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY) <= DAY(GETDATE()) and MONTH(LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY) <= MONTH(getdate())
```

and

```
select LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY
        from LAW_TAEEMASTER
        WHERE AND DATEPART(DAY,LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY) <= DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()) AND DATEPART(MONTH,LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY) <= DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())
```

but these just evaluate the month and day separately and as a number, greater than or less than, so it's excluding records. How can I get SQL to recognize these as part of a date and just ignore the year?

Answer (score 0):

**Explain the logic and code:** 
Use `CONVERT(varchar(5),<your_date> ,110))`. The `110` arguement means USA standard time and have an ouput like `mm-dd-yyyy`. Then we only take the first five character which is the month and day of the date.

> 110 = mm-dd-yyyy
>   read more about [cast and convert here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

**my sample table:**

```
MASTER_ENTRY
2017-08-30
2017-07-05
2017-07-04
```

**Then I executed this query**

```
SELECT LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY 
FROM LAW_TAEEMASTER
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(5),LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY ,110) <=  CONVERT(varchar(5),GETDATE() ,110)
```

**result:where month and day equal or earlier current month and day**

```
MASTER_ENTRY
2017-07-05
2017-07-04
```

I hope this helps and welcome to StackOverflow. If you find this answer or any other answer solves your problem please mark it as the solution. This will help the community and fellow programmers who run into the same problem in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using `month()` and `day()`:

```
where month(LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY) * 100 + day(LAW_TAEEMASTER.MASTR_ENTRY) < month(getdate()) * 100 + day(getdate())
```

If performance is an issue, I would recommend a computed column with an index.